# InvalidArgumentError: No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'CudnnRNN'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, gpu

I followed the steps provided here : https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu
to install tensorflow that works with my gpu, and use the cuDNN SDK
but for some reasons I still can not use it, and am still getting this error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'CudnnRNN' used by node sequential/cu_dnnlstm/CudnnRNN (defined at cudrnn.py:27) with these attrs: [input_mode="linear_input", T=DT_FLOAT, direction="unidirectional", rnn_mode="lstm", seed2=0, is_training=true, seed=0, dropout=0]
Registered devices: [CPU, XLA_CPU, XLA_GPU]
Registered kernels:
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_DOUBLE]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_FLOAT]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_HALF]
```

even though the GPU is registered but tensorflow claims that they can not find an OpKernel.

I am using:

tensoflow-gpu 1.14.0

Cuda 10.0

Ubuntu 18.04

P.S: I can run other code using tensorflow and by checking nvidia-smi I can see that the GPUs are getting used actually.

can anyone please help me knowing why I am getting this problem ?

this is the code I am trying to run:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.CuDNNLSTM(
        3,
        return_sequences=False),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
])

model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.1, decay=0.003), 
    loss=tf.keras.losses.mse)

model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=100, validation_split=0, shuffle=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Registered devices showing `XLA_GPU` which is optimized compiler but not same as `GPU` which the tensorflow library you are using expects,

You can check couple of ways to resolve,

- [Enable XLA for TF models](https://www.tensorflow.org/xla#enable_xla_for_tensorflow_models)
- [Check for build configurations of tensorflow for your device](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#tested_build_configurations)